# How to set background image with full width and responsive

Tags: css, responsive

Im trying to set a background image and set this to be full witdh but im only getting to see it centered.

```css
.wrapper-hero {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 1920px;
}

.wrapper-hero .hero-image {
  background: url('@{baseDir}images/hero-image.png') no-repeat top center;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: block;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 800px;
  width: 1200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-hero">
  <div class="hero-image"></div>
</div>
```

Any ideas? And the image is not responsive at all...

Comment: set hero-image width to 100% instead on giving it 1200px. It will be responsive then

Answer (score 3):

You're using `background-size` multiple times. Try this code.

```css
.hero-image {
      background: url('@{baseDir}images/hero-image.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
      width: 100%;
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
  }
```

Comment: But I dont want to give height as constant, what about in that case?

Comment: You can try to add `height: 100%` and `min-height: 100vh;` I've made a jsfiddle for you. Is this what you want? [https://jsfiddle.net/L8j9aevo/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/L8j9aevo/1/)

Comment: @PardeepJain you need to remember that the aspect ratio of the image will have to be maintained, so a "fixed" size in height or width direction should be specified, as far as I can see. I might be wrong though.